DX-70 Sideband leakage
My radio Alinco DX-70 transmits on both USB and LSB, when I set it to transmit on USB. Signal is visible in USB as well as in LSB, but signal strength is bit less in LSB. It appears that radio is transmitting as DSB. Now my question how this can happen. What could be the problem that makes a SSB radio to DSB ? One more observation is that, when I transmit on LSB, then it is fine, there is no transmission on USB at this time. I need some help as how to diagnose this problem. At least if I can understand where is the problem, then I can determine if it repairable or not.
Thanks

Can you confirm that the transceiver is from around 1996 or so? My first thought is that you may have some failing components in the modulation circuitry.

1998 approx is the purchasing date

I would suspect components have become marginal

Classic SSB generator first generates a DSB/SC and then uses a crystal or ceramic filter to choose USB or LSB. In Alinco DX-70, that filtering seems to be done in FL2, FL3 and FL4. Those seem to be 455kHz ceramic filters. The problem you described is consistent with the mechanism, and the unwanted sideband rejection is less than perfect. Some ceramic filters deteriorate over time, especially when DC is applied to the component (FL2, FL3, and FL4 in Alinco DX-70 have DC bias applied to both inputs and outputs). Deteriorated ceramic filters often generate a lot of noise, as well.
https://qrpblog.com/download/alinco-dx-70-th-eh-service-manual/

yes component issues. Needed to replace the the filter. I handed over it to a pro as this was too complex for me.

You might want to consider your report as a comment to your question or to my answer. Also, please don't forget to accept (green checkmark) my answer...

this looks like a response to the other answer that should probably be converted to a comment.
